# Determine newline return method in PHP

Tags: php, newline

What would be the best way to detect newline return method in PHP. CR, LF or CR+LF
And if possible convert it to specified type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
define('NL_NIX', "\n");
define('NL_WIN', "\r\n");
define('NL_MAC', "\r");


function newline_type($string)
{
    if (strpos($string, NL_WIN) !== false) {
        return NL_WIN;
    } elseif(strpos($string, NL_MAC) !== false) {
        return NL_MAC;
    } elseif(strpos($string, NL_NIX) !== false) {
        return NL_NIX;
    }
}
```

Checks what kind of newline is in the string. 0 is returned when no newline is found.

To normalize/standardize all newlines use the following function:

```
function newline_convert($string, $newline)
{
    return str_replace(array(NL_WIN, NL_MAC, NL_NIX), $newline, $string);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I like the idea of your functions, but they're a little verbose. In newline_type, why not just `return` after every `if` instead of storing it as `$result`? Then just `return 0;` at the end. No need for the variable. With `newline_convert`, why not just `return str_replace...`?

Comment: @Josh - it is good practice to split up the code. easier for debugging or what. I'm used to it because I learnt my lesson - finding out what went wrong and so on. it's fine if you combine them into a single line too.

Comment: But there's a difference between 'good practice' and being unnecessarily verbose. For instance, in your first function you create an entirely new variable just to store something you don't need to store. And I fail to see how (in this instance) it makes anything clearer; if anything it just makes things more complex. Just some food for thought. ;)

Comment: oh well updated. the reason why I wanted a single return and store the return value into `$result` was because I thought I could detect several newline type and combine. e.g. if you have "\r\n" and "\n" in your string, it will return `(2 & 4)`. Something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The constant `PHP_EOL` contains the platform specific newline character.

Comment: This is the best and easiest way to check. I used the following code to seperate the lines of a textarea:

$somearray = explode(PHP_EOL, $sometext);

Comment: Note that the lines of a text area would depend on the clients newline character. So in that case I wouldn't recommend you use `PHP_EOL`

Answer (score 1):

This will test a string for a newline character (CR or LF):

```
function has_newline($string)
{
    return (strpos($string, "\r") !== false || strpos($string, "\n") !== false);
}
```

(`\r` means CR and `\n` means LF)

You can use the same thinking to convert them. For example, this function converts all CRs to LFs in a given string:

```
function replace_returns($string)
{
    return str_replace("\r", "\n", $string);
}
```

Comment: i reckon replace_returns($string) you wrote works nicely on cross-platform. imagine \r\n (single newline in Windows), it will be converted to \n\n (2 new lines in *nux!)

Comment: I understand your point, but my purpose wasn't to imagine every circumstance for the OP, it was to point him in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a $string = nl2br($string) so that your line break is changed to

```
<br />.
```

Then you can manipulate the string, e.g. split it up by the first occurance of

```
<br />
```

like this:

```
list($first, $second) = explode('<br />', $string, 2);
```